# ACRCloud song Recognize

Tags: c#, sdk, mp3, acrcloud

Hey all I have the following code from the ACRCloud c# demo:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var config = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    config.Add("host", "us-west-2.api.acrcloud.com");
    config.Add("access_key", "key here....");
    config.Add("access_secret", "secret here...");
    config.Add("timeout", 10); // seconds

    ACRCloudRecognizer re = new ACRCloudRecognizer(config);

    // It will skip 0 seconds from the beginning of test.mp3.
    string result = re.RecognizeByFile("C:\\temp\\acrcloud_sdk_csharp-master\\01Track01.mp3", 80);
    //string result2 = re.Recognize("C:\\temp\\acrcloud_sdk_csharp-master\\01Track01", 80);
    Console.WriteLine(result);

    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\temp\acrcloud_sdk_csharp-master\01Track01.mp3", FileMode.Open))
    {
        using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(fs))
        {
            byte[] datas = reader.ReadBytes((int)fs.Length);
            // It will skip 0 seconds from the beginning of datas.
            result = re.RecognizeByFileBuffer(datas, datas.Length, 80);
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

For both **results** I am getting the return of:

```
{"status":{
    "msg":"No result",
    "code":1001,
    "version":"1.0"
}}
```

Not sure what I am doing incorrect.... Any help would be great!

Comment: im not sure what you are doing wrong, but maybe try using the sample code here?

https://github.com/acrcloud/webapi_example/blob/master/identify%20protocol%201%20(recommended)/IdentifyProtocolV1.cs

Comment: That produces the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the project you have created the problem is you attached your own bucket to this project but you didn't upload any files to this bucket, in other words: your database is empty, that's why you could not recognize anything. If you want to recognize music, please refer to [this tutorial](https://www.acrcloud.com/docs/tutorials/identify-music-by-sound/) and attach "ACRCloud Music" bucket to your project then you should be able to recognize music.